# How to assign datareader data into generic List ( of T )

Tags: vb.net, list, generics

I would like assign datareader data into generic List ( of T ).

I do not want to read the specific column item name. I want to make it dynamic.

Example code:

```
Shared Function FormatUserList(ByVal PoReader As OracleDataReader) As List(Of Users)
    Dim oUserList As New List(Of Users)()
    Dim oUser As Users
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = PoReader.GetSchemaTable()

    Do While PoReader.Read()
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        oUser = New Users()

        oUser.LoginId = Convert.ToString(PoReader("LoginId"))
        oUser.Password = Convert.ToString(PoReader("Password"))
        oUser.FirstName = Convert.ToString(PoReader("FirstName"))
        oUser.LastName = Convert.ToString(PoReader("LastName"))
        oUser.NRIC = Convert.ToString(PoReader("NRIC"))
        oUser.MobileNo = Convert.ToInt64(PoReader("MobileNo"))
        oUser.Address = Convert.ToString(PoReader("Address"))
        oUser.Zip = Convert.ToInt64(PoReader("Zip"))
        oUser.State = Convert.ToInt64(PoReader("state"))
        oUser.UserGroupId = Convert.ToInt64(PoReader("UserGroupId"))
        oUser.CompanyId = Convert.ToInt64(PoReader("CompanyId"))
        oUser.Active = Convert.ToInt64(PoReader("Active"))
        oUserList.Add(oUser)
    Loop

    Return oUserList
End Function
```

I need something like below, but I receive an error when looping the 2nd row data to `SetValue`.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
Do While PoReader.Read()

  oUserGroup = New UserGroups()

  Dim type As Type = GetType(UserGroups) 
  Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        sColName = row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName")
        type.GetProperty(sColName).SetValue(obj, PoReader(row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName")), Nothing)
        oUserGroupList.Add(obj)
    Next row
Loop
```

Comment: Have you considered using a Micro-ORM like Dapper?

Comment: Indeed, this is basically *exactly* what "dapper" does, except dapper uses meta-programming via IL generation to be insanely fast. And it handles the actual query setup too, since that is unnecessarily convoluted in ADO.NET

Comment: Besides the error, you are missing an important point in the second approach - the PoReader may return the value as OracleDbType rather than System.DateTime, System.Int32 and etc, which could fail with typecasts - in other words, the `Convert.ToXXX` call is missing

Comment: Why do you have an inner loop while goes over the **rows** (not columns) of a data-table for every row in the result? What is `dt.Rows`? and how is it relevant to `type` or `PoReader` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what the role of `dt` is here; however, a *very basic* reflection-based loop (using C# - you would have to translate) is shown in the second example below.

However, before doing that, I *really* think you should take a look at ["dapper"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper), which makes data access (including parameterization) as simple as:

```
string region = "North";
var people = conn.Query<Person>("select * from People where Region=@region",
           new { region }).ToList();
```

(with support for most common data scenarios you would want, including type translation - and more insane optimization than you can shake an IL-based stick at)

And to do it the slow way with reflection, something like:

```
static List<T> Read<T>(IDataReader reader)
    where T : class, new()
{
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        // at least one row: resolve the properties
        PropertyInfo[] props = new PropertyInfo[reader.FieldCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(reader.GetName(i),
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            if(prop != null && prop.CanWrite) props[i] = prop;
        }

        do
        {
            var obj = new T();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                var prop = props[i];
                if (prop == null) continue; // not mapped

                object val = reader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : reader[i];
                prop.SetValue(obj, val);
            }
            results.Add(obj);
        } while (reader.Read());
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, 
Thanks for the answer. 

I'm stucked at the  below . What class I should set ?
 " var obj = new T() " .
I'm new with "Dapper". It might take time for me. but I will spend some time on it when i free.

Comment: @user2578713 the `T` comes from the generic type parameter definition - so it is whatever the **caller** supplies